# Unable to Apply iOS MDM Configuration Profile

Tags: ios, mdm

This maybe a really dumb question but has had me stumped for days now. I have setup an MDM server. Then through the iPCU (iPhone Configuration Utility) I push a configuration profile with the relevant checkin and server URLs. I also add a credentials certificate installed on my machine and specify that as the identity.

After I push the profile to the device however, I get the following error...

```
MDM: Cannot Authenticate. Error: NSError:

Desc   : A transaction with the server at https://heshang.abc.lk/MDMServer/checkin has 
failed with the status 404.
US Desc: A transaction with the server at https://heshang.abc.lk/MDMServer/checkin has failed with the status 404.
Domain : MCHTTPTransactionErrorDomain
Code   : 23001
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "https://heshang.abc.lk/MDMServer/checkin",
    404
)
```

I checked whether the check-in url is accessible through device and it is. So what is causing this authentication error that I am getting ? It is not an SSL error either because I have accessed the MDM server via the device (an iPad) and I don't get an HTTPS error when doing so.

What is causing this authentication error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device uses `HTTP PUT` when it contacts the MDM Server. Can you verify your web server is configured to handle/route an `HTTP PUT` request correctly?

Comment: Thank you VERY much for that answer... I actually tested this by using the following code `<form id="form1" runat="server" method="PUT">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>`

and accessed this page via the iPad.. and had a debug point on the button click event handler hit. Doesn't that mean that PUT is enabled on the server ? Is there any other way to verify this ?

Comment: You can't test it from the browser. Browsers only support the `GET` and `POST` methods. You can test it with the curl command line tool. The command would look something like this: `curl -k -X PUT "https://heshang.abc.lk/MDMServer/checkin" -d checkin-data.plist`

Comment: Thank you very much.. when attempting with curl, I got the proper error message that the method was not allowed. Issue solved. Here are the references i used to configure the IIS server and web.config, so that anyone else having the same issue can use it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170628/httpwebrequest-put-error-status-405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695587/enabling-put-on-iis-7-5-for-an-ashx-handler-using-windows-authentication

Comment: @HeshanPerera    Hi Heshan..I am getting same error in consol log in IPCU(iphone configuration utility) while trying to install device on to MDM. I am still not able to resolve my problem.

Comment: @sau what was your curl output ?

Comment: @HeshanPerera Please help me in setting up MDM server for ios devices. Please, Can i have your email id ?

Comment: @HeshanPerera I am using MAMP server.

Comment: $ curl -k -X PUT "localhost:8000/server1"; -d sample.plist ------------------- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>301 Moved Permanently</title> </head><body> <h1>Moved Permanently</h1> <p>The document has moved <a href="localhost:8000/server1/">here</a>.</p>; </body></html>